# How can I uninstall python 2.7 and reinstall 3.5 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python

I d like to ask a clean removal method, so that python 3 will not be diturbed by previous version.
I am not sure how the python2.7 be installed, because it was not me who did it. And i am totally new in Linux, so I really not sure what should I do...

Here is the information when I check the python version.
Thanks!! :)

```
administrator@TUBVLMF-AWR163:~$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# zipimport: found 13 names in /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runipy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
# zipimport: found 135 names in /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.6-py2.7.egg
import encodings # directory /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun  2 2014, 12:34:02) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
dlopen("/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
```

Comment: *IF* you succeed, your system will break. Many essential elements depend on `python2` in 14.04.  "disturbed by previous version"  is a none issue, versions are called from the shebang if the file has the shebang, is executable and called without version.

Comment: If you want python 3, then use `python3` as the command rather than `python` which will always be python 2.

Comment: simple answer, **don't**

Answer (score 7):

By default in latest Ubuntu release python and python3 are already included and if you completely remove python 2.7 it may break your system 
type in terminal

```
python3
```

to open python 3 interpreter
and when you run your scripts type

```
python3 Scriptname
```

and if not already included type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 6):

> I am not sure how the python2.7 be installed, because it was not me
>   who did it. And i am totally new in Linux, so I really not sure what
>   should I do...

First, to check if YOU have manually installated python2.7, do

`apt show python2.7`

Within all this infos there's a line `APT-Manual-Installed: no`. If this is NO you shouldn't probably uninstall it! For all packages, this rule is often true.

So, as said it isn't wise removing python2.7.
I suggest to add simply an alias to your bash's configuration file, so when you'll write `python` in your terminal, it will be like writing `python3`. 
This is useful, but potentially can create misunderstanding.

**HOW TO DO**

Add

`alias python=python3`

at the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file (or simply `echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc`)

Than do:

`source ~/.bashrc`

from the terminal to update bash with the changes.

Comment: Note: `apt` (instead of apt-get) appeared first in 16.04