# What will happen to old version of python when I upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

I have 3 versions of python on my Ubuntu computer - 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, and I want to get rid off all these 3 altogether and just have only one version of python3 when I upgrade to 18.04. What will happen to them when I upgrade? And also how can I completely uninstall any one version of python from my current Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: "And also how can I completely uninstall any one version of python from my current Ubuntu desktop?" The reverse way you installed it. Used "apt install"?  Then you use "apt purge" . Used source? Then "rm".

Comment: Oh, and if you installed it with the base Ubuntu you remove the base Ubuntu. So I advice to keep 1 of 2.* and 1 of 3.* as those are from your base install.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Bionic Beaver (18.04) won't change your Python installations as long as the upgrades go well and as planned. I would recommend to make a backup first, because sometimes they don't.

With 18.04 Python 2 is no longer comes preinstalled, and Python 3 has been updated to 3.6 - but as said: your manual installation stays as it is.

To uninstall, you can use e.g. (change for your need)

```
 sudo apt-get remove python2.7
```

but there could be some dependencies preventing you to so so. Backward compatibility isn't so easy with Python. My personal recommondation would be to keep at least one 2.x version.

Some credit goes here:
[How can I remove python 2.7 after installing python 3.3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315015/how-can-i-remove-python-2-7-after-installing-python-3-3)

If you just don't want to type `python3`, you could also add an alias to your bash's configuration file, so when you'll write python in your terminal, it will be like writing python3. This is useful, but potentially **can create misunderstanding**.

##### HOW TO DO

Add

```
alias python=python3
```

at the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file (or simply enter this in your console with sufficient rights `echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bashrc`)

Than do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

from the terminal to update bash with the changes ([Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850093/how-can-i-uninstall-python-2-7-and-reinstall-3-5-in-ubuntu-14-04)).